# Implementing swap for class with std::mutex

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex, swap

Suppose we have a `class` with a `std::mutex`:

```
class Foo
{
    std::mutex mutex_;
    std::string str_;
    // other members etc
public:
    friend void swap(Foo& lhs, Foo& rhs) noexcept;
}
```

What is the appropriate way to implement the `swap` method here? Is it required/safe to lock each mutex separately and then swap everything? e.g.

```
void swap(Foo& lhs, Foo& rhs) noexcept
{
    using std::swap;
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock_lhs {lhs.mutex_}, lock_rhs {rhs.mutex_};
    swap(ls.str_, rhs.str_);
    // swap everything else
}
```

I've seen that in C++17, `std::lock_guard` will have a [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) taking multiple mutexes for avoiding deadlock, but I'm not sure if that's an issue here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `std::lock()` to acquire the locks in a non-deadlocking way.

If you want to use `std::lock_guard`, have them adopt the locks once taken:

```
std::lock(lhs.mutex_, rhs.mutex_);
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock_a(lhs.mutex_, std::adopt_lock);
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock_b(rhs.mutex_, std::adopt_lock);
//swap actions
swap(ls.str_, rhs.str_);
```

If you prefer `std::unique_lock`, then construct them without locking, then call `std::lock()` to lock them both (this also works with `std::lock_guard`):

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock_a(lhs.mutex_, std::defer_lock);
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock_b(rhs.mutex_, std::defer_lock);
std::lock(lock_a, lock_b);
//swap actions
swap(ls.str_, rhs.str_);
```

In both cases, you should first test for `lhs` and `rhs` being the same object, because using `std::lock` with one mutex twice is undefined behavior:

```
if (&lhs == &rhs)
    return;
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your swap implementation is safe. If another algorithm tries to lock `rhs.mutex_` first and then `lhs.mutex_`, you may end up with a deadlock. Try [`std::lock()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock) instead.